# how to prevent multiple instances of the repeated execute event in mysql

Tags: events, scheduler

I have a question would like to ask about preventing multiple instances execute simultaneously in MySql event scheduler. The following code is my event scheduler :

```
CREATE EVENT WalletDequeue_Event
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 2 MINUTE
COMMENT 'Update lotte_wallet data with wallet_queue_mngt data.'
DO
  CALL walletDequeue();
```

I have searched about preventing multiple instances simultaneously execute with google, and the answer is "you should institute a mechanism to prevent simultaneous instances. For example, you could use the GET_LOCK() function, or row or table locking.".

Could anybody tell me how to do this?

Best regards, 
Phanna

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is little bit old, I will add the answer for one possible approach here for future reference.

Following article explains how to use MySQL GET_LOCK and RELEASE_LOCK functions to prevent having multiple instances of the same event simultaneously.
https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/02/25/using-mysql-event-scheduler-and-how-to-prevent-contention/

Example code from the article:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT testlock_event ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 SECOND DO
BEGIN
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
 BEGIN
   DO RELEASE_LOCK('testlock_event');
 END;
 IF GET_LOCK('testlock_event', 0) THEN
   -- add some business logic here, for example:
   -- insert into test.testlock_event values(NULL, NOW());
  END IF;
  DO RELEASE_LOCK('testlock_event');
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```